# After creating Role with password in PostgreSQL, by default I am able to access some of the tables without granting select permission?

Tags: postgresql

Ex: I have tables Table_A, Table_B, Table_C

I have created Role(user) called Username
Create User username with password 'pwd'

Without granting select permission to username able to access some of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

The tables (Table_A, Table_B, Table_C) which have created are in public schema, so without granting select permission we can able to access the tables.